# How to fetch the row data very efficiently in a table?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have a scenario to read the contents of a table and print the same, based on certain conditions.

```
ColA     ColB      ColC   ColD       ColE
1        Matt      Dep1   NY         1234
2        Joy       Dep2   Sydeny     1234
3        Matt      Dep1   Canada     1234
4       Stewart    Dep3   Sydney     1234
```

This is how the table looks. I am fetching table content and printing it.
Even I could able to get what i want. Say, I want to store the rows in an array, where ColB contains Matt and ColC contains Dep1. It goes by, fetching the number of rows and then keep on iterating for entire rows, altering the tr[row_index] for as many as fro loops. Eventhough the expected data not present in the later rows. This is time consuming, if we have 1000 of rows.

is there any way to optimize it ? can we do by `tr[row_index]` contains multiple column values, like this ?

```
tdata = driver.get_text("xpath=//table[@id='table1234']/tbody" #tdata will have the entire table content
rows = driver.get_matching_xpath_count("//table[@id='table1234']/tbody//tr")
     for i in range(1, int(rows)+1):
         if "matt" = driver.get_text("xpath=//table[@id='table1234']/tbody/tr["+str(i)+"]/td[2]") and "Dep1" == driver.get_text("xpath=//table[@id='table1234']/tbody/tr["+str(i)+"]/td[3]"):
                    row_rext = row_text=driver.get_text("xpath=//table[@id='table1234']/tbody/tr["+str(i)+"]")
#print or store in a list, should not be a problem
```

Any possibilities with reg-ex ? or any other efficient way ?

**[Updated]**

```
I could able to achieve it with reg-ex in a faster way. Any selenium way to achieve the same ?
```

Comment: Does the page have jQuery?

Comment: Once you fetched rows, the child XPath expressions should be relative to each row, not to search from the root all over again... that makes no sense

Comment: @Borna : exactly, looping through entire doesn't make sense. How can i make it efficient and optimize ?

Comment: May I know the reason,. Why someone down voted ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not gonna write you a code, but I can give you a tip.

When you evaluate the xpath below,

xpath:

> //table[@id='table1234']/tbody/tr[./td[2]/text()='Matt' and
>   ./td[3]/text()='Dep1']

you will have a list of tr elements.
So all you have to do is loop through the returned list of tr elements and for each element extract its **child nodes** (td).

-

There is also another approach if columns count is fixed (which is your case).

Look at this xpath:

> //table[@id='table1234']/tbody/tr[./td[2]/text()='Matt' and
>   ./td[3]/text()='Dep1']/td

notice the appended `/td`, this means we gonna fetch all td elements, which will give us a list of `matched_rows_count*columns_count` number of elements.
This approach will only work if each row has a fixed number of columns(same number of td elements).

So, how to extract values and save them as rows somewhere else?
Since you know the columns count, you also know the starting and ending position of each row in the list. Taking your table as an example, the first row (its td elements) are in the returned list at positions 0,1,2,3,4, second row is positioned at 5,6,7,8,9, and so on...

**UPDATE**:

Here is an update that shows the usage of `contains` with the given example.

> //table/tbody/tr[./td[position()=2 and contains(.,'Matt')] and
>   ./td[position()=3 and contains(.,'Dep1')]]/td

Using `.` will make it to search inside every `text node` that is inside `td`

check this:

```
 ./td[position()=2 and contains(.,'Matt')]
```

it will return a node set, but it is valid because **empty node set** is treated as **false**.

Comment: Thanks, got it. in above xpath, instead of text()='' , is there anything to check as contains. If a td element  contains a sentence, 'Matt is a good boy'. In this case, i would like to check if that td contains Matt.

Answer (score 0):

you could utilize the xpath.

> let's say you want to find row where ColB contains Matt and ColC
>   contains Dep1

The xpath would be

```
row_elm = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='table1234']/tbody/tr/td[position()=2 and text()='matt']/../td[position()=3 and text()='Dep1']/..
```

Comment: what does it return ? Is it looping through entire rows ? Say if there are 1000 rows, my logic will loop for 1000 times ,even though there are only 5 matching conditions. How does this work ?

Comment: it doesn't loop though all the rows, it will simple find the row whose `second column` will contain text `matt` and `third column` contains text `dep1` if you will use that with `findElements` it will find all the matching rows with `findElement` just first matching row. much faster then loop

Comment: I used 'find_elements_by_xpath' , it returns me list of matching objects. How to proceed further with those objects ? can you help me with simple example ?